# How to make dynamic ReactJS components match in height, and align in content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

With ReactJS, I'm generating the content of components based on dynamic state values.

I want the distances to match, and not like the picture below, when longer strings are rendered (like in the upper text), my components become unequal in height, and the text components below jumping down as well:
[image: two components of unequal length]

The code that I use right now is Rebass to make the two parent columns, and for the text in the components within it I'm using styled components like so:

```
const Title = styled.h1`
font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
font-style: slim;
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 1em;
text-align: center;
color: black;
`;

const Text = styled.h6`
font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
font-style: thin100;
text-align: justify;
color: black;
`;
```

and within render():

```
<Title>{this.props.title}</Title>
<Text>
  <b>Cuisine: </b>
  {this.props.cuisine.toString().replace(/,/g, " ")}
</Text>
```

What's the best way to make my components align? Do I have to give each text element a fixed height? If so, how would be the best way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you'll never get three rows, you can just fix the height to the size that matches two rows. That way, with only one row, spacing will be the same.

Other way around is, if you want to keep title on the top, smileys on the bottom and other content in the middle to place `justify-content: space-between` on the parent element to spread those three things around the screen.